# VAT Refund Process for Cash Purchases

Tags: amsterdam, tax-refunds

I will soon be traveling to Amsterdam and plan to purchase some goods at the Apple store, and would be requesting a refund of the VAT since I am not a resident of the EU.

I did [some research](http://www.iamsterdam.com/en-GB/experience/plan-your-trip/practical-info/communication-money-matters) and found that in Netherlands VAT is 21% (wow!) and only refundable on purchases more than 50 EUR.

Also, I found out that there are two services available at the airport that can help with refunds (vatfree and global-blue).

All the services can refund you on your credit card, or wire transfer to an account in the EU. What if I didn't buy through a credit card? Do they then wire outside of the EU or send a check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Global Blue:

1. Go to the Refund counter displaying a Global Blue logo.
2. Present your stamped, completed Tax Free Forms to receive the refund in cash or
   to credit card.
3. If you're in a rush, mail your stamped, completed Tax Free
   Forms using the Global Blue envelope and receive your refund on your
   credit card. Adding your e-mail address on the Tax Free Form enables
   quicker and more effective communication between You and Global Blue
   Customer Services.
4. Remember that at some airports a cash handling fee per “Form” will be charged should you require an Immediate Refund in cash.
5. The refund you receive is the VAT minus Global Blue’s service fee (and minus the possible immediate cash refund on Point 4).

Best regards

Comment: If I am correctly reading https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/global/Documents/Tax/dttl-tax-european-vat-refund-guide-2015.pdf (page 189-191), VAT on purchases in Netherlands can only be refunded for business supplies and not things that tourists buy.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Only use [vatfree.com](https://www.vatfree.com/calculator/). They will give you the most refund.

[you can choose to have the total refund transferred to a credit card, paypal, bank account or a good cause.](https://www.vatfree.com/#how)

c.f. [Global Blue](http://www.globalblue.com/customer-services/tax-free-shopping/refund-calculator/).

Comment: vatfree's estimator on €600 says €74,35 and Global Blue estimates €59.  Are there no ways for an individual person to go direct?  https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/global/Documents/Tax/dttl-tax-european-vat-refund-guide-2015.pdf sounds like if it's possible it's acute proctalgia.